# How to create popup appearing under visible element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on replacing a window.open() notification system and think to implement this with javascript.

I now have a link, which when clicked fires an ajax request. The response is now shown in a window.open() popup, but instead I want this to be a div that the user can close by clicking on it.
The popup though should appear below the link, just like some sort of tooltip.

Can I get any pointers on how to do this or (jquery) scripts that do something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Below as in `z-index`? Tooltips are generally a higher `z-index` than the element they are associated with.

Comment: I would suggest you google first, try to get something working, then ask a specific question after you have done that.  here you are just asking us to google something for you. here's a link to get you started:  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Adding_Elements

Comment: No, I mean visible, but under the button. It can be quite simple of course, but I tried myself and can't get the popups to appears correctly under the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep:

http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltips

I personally like this one for your needs: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

Again many to choose from

Comment: There are a ton of them out there some even come with themes, if you get stuck implementing the one you like ask a more pointed question about the issue.

Comment: I have experimented with tipsy, but I cannot get it to work as I want. I'll try your suggestion!

Comment: Why do you want it "visable" under the link? Do you have an element that is opaque and your trying to make it appear to slide up on mouseover?

Comment: I mean south of the link, not layered under it. I just need a tooltip which I can display programmatically as well as allow the user to hide it before a timeout. Not easy to find it seems...

Comment: So you want an element to show under a link and it will close on mouseout (of the link it is attached to?) or it closes when it is clicked? Sorry I am trying to understand so I can put together a code sample for you... Does not sound too difficult to program is all...

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with modifying tipsy(). I'll post back when I find a solution. Don't waste your time on my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for something that jQuery has already done for you.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

It is simple and easy to use!
Feel free if to ask me any questions if you don't understand the plugin :)

Actually, after reading again your comment, tooltip is really what you are looking for. So give credit to our fellow!

Comment: Indeed the dialog is not what I need. Thank you for the effort!